# Symfony - User authentication using external user database + API

Tags: authentication, symfony, authenticator

I need to build a Symfony application where the users are not stored in the local database as Entity: the application uses an external user database located at a  separate domain, and I am looking at authentication via API.
I can't find any extensive examples about this, not even in the documentation, so I came up with my own implementation which I don't think is good at all.

In my app I created the following:

- A class User, which implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
- My UserAuthenticator class is essentially a standard one
- My UserProvider is what makes the difference, as it makes an HTTP request to https://externaluserdb.example.com (fake url for dummy purpose) in order to fetch user information, instead of relying on local database.

However, this is where I'm getting confused. I have two approaches in mind, but none of these seem to be secure or good practice at all

---

**APPROACH 1 (must be really wrong)**

- Application makes API call to https://externaluserdb.example.com providing `username` only
- https://externaluserdb.example.com returns the user's hashed password (I think this is terrible?)
- Application locally hashes `password` and compares it with value from remote database; logs user in if it's a match
- If authentication is successful, application fetches the rest of user data from https://externaluserdb.example.com (not sure how, unless correct password is provided)

---

**APPROACH 2**
This makes a lot more sense to me, but I am not sure it's good practice as I would be passing the clear password to the third-party service (even though it's https, I'm not sure it's good)

- Application makes API call to https://externaluserdb.example.com providing `username` and `password`
- https://externaluserdb.example.com checks credentials and responds with a status (authentication OK or NO) and user data if authentication is successful

Comment: Is your question about Salesforce that owns database.com or are you using it as example URL? In either case you need clarification.

Comment: I was not referring to the real database.com, I used it as a dummy name to represent the external user database. Apologies for the confusion

Comment: I changed to use the correct domain from the RFC standards: example.com. It is never appropriate just  to "make-up" a domain for documentation purposes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com

Comment: Does the external user database (the identity provider) provide authentication via OAuth? If so you could consider using the authorization code grant flow for having the user sign in to the external app, retrieve the user's identity and then use that information to sign them into your app automatically.

Comment: No OAuth so far, just a remote login via JSON